# r shiny : how to do "scorecard" table styling?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using knitr::kable function  to show data from last row from dataframe,
It's working, but how to do some styling for better look like scorecard ?
Means to change label and output from table only data row, not label.
e.g. now shows

```
Confirmed
60,000,000
```

and I would like to show

```
Total Confirmed
60,000,000
```

Also the styling should be better, without row lines something like this...
[image]

Here is piece of my current code

```
 sidebarLayout(
    position='right',
    sidebarPanel(
      tableOutput("table_date"),
      tableOutput("table1")
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      plotlyOutput("distPlot")
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
...
date_last <- tail(conf_data[ , c("date")],1)
  conf_last <- tail(conf_data[ , c("confirmed")],1)
  
  output$table1 <- function() {
    conf_last %>% 
      knitr::kable(format = "html", row.names = FALSE, align='l') %>% 
      kable_styling()
  }
    
    output$table_date <- function() {
      date_last %>%
        knitr::kable(format = "html", row.names = FALSE) %>%
        kable_styling()
      
    }
```

And here is my current  working site
http://webcovid19.online/

Comment: Looks that maybe I found solution to  rename labels with col.names function and add header with  kable_styling add_header_above; anyway col.names just temporary change the name or persist change column name?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with
`kable_styling (font_size)`

Comment: How would a post which the OP themselves posted to say that they found the answer, and says exactly what the answer is, *not* be an answer? [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27768604)